# Where is the ToDos.sdf file in the Breeze Tutorial

Tags: breeze

This may be a stupid question. I am playing around with Breeze and have made a new Web project and added the NUGet packages and it runs perfectly. I am following this document:
http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-server which says "The Todo database itself is not included in the download. Rather the application (re)generates it from scratch, with mock data, every time the server starts. You'll find it as the hidden "Todos.sdf" file in the App_Data folder."

However, I am unable to find it under my VS2012 project - I have no App_Data folder (I have hidden folders in Windows 7 turned on). There is no information in the web config at all from the sample - I don't understand how EF CodeFirst knows where to make it.

The reason I am asking is that I am trying to integrate Breeze with a DotNetNuke module (with a PhoneGap app, but this is nothing to do with that) and I am having problems with this (invalid login) and want to check the actual database, but I can't find it...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you run the Todo sample solution, the Todos.sdf file will be generated at .\breeze-runtime-plus-1.3.4\Samples\Todo\Todo\App_Data.

The DB is dropped/recreated each time the solution is executed. You might change that in TodoDatabaseinitializer.cs.

Comment: Thanks - where is this path? \breeze-runtime-plus-1.3.4\   I have created a new project called WebApplication1 and NuGetted the Breeze.WebApiSample.1.3.4 to add the relevant files to it. See my project structure. I was expecting a hidden App_data under this project (which is running correct and saving ToDo items -I just can't work out where). How is it possible with no connection string info in the web.config? - See screenshot:  http://screencast.com/t/5bX6YIWqcVLE

Comment: A provided the path of the Todo sample downloaded at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download. Once you unzip it, follow the path and it your lead to where the .sdf file is created in that solution. If you check the sample config file, you will see that there is a connectionString there (<add name="TodosContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Todos.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />). You could also define it in the context - by convention, the context creates a database for you on localhost\SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: Ok, I can see that in the Samples web.config. The problem I am having is when I NuGet the Breeze.WebApiSample to my new blank Web project (the screenshot in my comment above). There is no mention of Todo.sdf or any App_data folder and yet it works - I do not understand this - where is the data being stored in the NuGetted sample? (thanks for you answers btw, I appreciate the help)